# Ninject inject add an element to collection when I create the collection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject, ninject-2

I'm using MVVM light and have set up the binding as following:

```
class TestModule:NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<ICollection<Element>>().To<Collection<Element>>();
        Bind<Element>().ToSelf();
    }
}
```

When I try to get a ICollection I get a collection with ONE element. I expect an exmpty collection.

```
    var _kernel = new StandardKernel(new TestModule());

    var col = _kernel.Get<ICollection<Element>>();
    Console.WriteLine("Count={0}", col.Count);   //Write "Count=1", Expect "Count=0"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is answered on the [Ninject mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/ninject/browse_thread/thread/28ecade13bf5cd45).

This behavior is expected. When a collection is injected, it will find all bindings 
that match the generic parameter and add them to the collection being 
injected. If you remove your binding on Element, an empty collection would 
be injected.

Another [example is given](http://groups.google.com/group/ninject/msg/544d6e7137a233d6) showing what can be done based on this behavior.

Comment: This is infuriating, counterintuitive and totally not-useful! There seems to be no obvious way to force Ninject to inject empty collections into a type. I don't **want** a dummy object in the collection! Just do as you're told, Ninject!